# Device recognized in ADB but not in shell

Tags: android, adb

When I use ADB, my phone is recognized. However, once I enter the shell, the phone mysteriously disappears. This is weird especially because the shell lists "root@nozomi", as "nozomi" is the phone's code name.

[image]

And because it is not recognized, I can't, for example, push files:

[image]

Comment: Are you perchance executing `adb push` in your `adb shell`, i.e. **on your phone**?

Comment: Great question.  Realistically, there are devs who *have* typed host commands into the device shell, **and then there are devs who *will***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `adb` command is available both on your phone and your host/development machine. However, it is not much useful on your phone from the shell.

`adb shell` opens a unix command shell **on your phone**. Commands you enter here are executed on your phone.

When you execute `adb devices` in the adb shell, you ask your phone if it has any *other* phones connected to it via the android debugging interface. And clearly your phone tells you, that this is not the case.

Same thing holds for `adb push` you are asking your phone to push a file to another phone via adb. Since none are connected, you get the error message.

Try exiting the `adb shell` again and execute commands on the host machine instead.